# Disabled input tag doesn't enable when reload current page

Tags: jquery, html, browser, reload

An 'input button tag' is disabled  with a value, on clicking of that button , but when reload current page in browser doesn't change the button to enable(disabled = 'false') , only value in the button will be removed .

I used an 'a href' in that page it will redirect to old state(disabled = 'false').

### Before Click of button

```
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="button(0,0);count += 1; counts(count);" id="buttonId" class="button-click" name="button">
```

### After Click of button

```
    <input disabled="disabled" name="button" class="button-click" id="buttonId" onclick="button(0,0);count += 1; counts(count);" value="YES" type="button">
```

### After reload of webpage

```
    <input disabled="disabled" name="button" class="button-click" id="buttonId" onclick="button(0,0);count += 1; counts(count);" value="" type="button">
```

I am using jQuery, on button click I have written code to disable that input tag .

Is it possible to write code on 'reload button in browser'  in jQuery or any other idea

Answer (score 2):

Although it has been almost a year that your question is not answered, and I found it because I have same problem. I found the solution at another discussion, here it is the link [Jquery UI button gets disabled on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719044/jquery-ui-button-gets-disabled-on-refresh)

You just put the line `$('button').removeAttr('disabled').button();`