# JQuery click event not working after page refresh on Firefox

Tags: jquery, events, firefox

I have the following JQuery module, which collapses a form on the page, so that clicking a button will reveal it:

```
(function (jQuery) {
  "use strict";

  //Attach this new method to jQuery
  jQuery.fn.extend({

    module_content_form_expander: function (options) {

      // Iterate over the current set of matched elements
      return this.each(function () {

        var form_expander_thing = jQuery(this);
        var strButtonInit = options.initial_button_text;
        var strButtonActive = options.active_button_text;

        var module_thing = form_expander_thing.find('.module-content');
        var content = form_expander_thing.find('.visible-content');
        var button = form_expander_thing.find('.trigger');
        var cancel = form_expander_thing.find('.cancel-action');

        module_thing.hide();
        content.css('opacity', 0);
        button.css('margin-top', '0.7em');
        button.attr('value', strButtonInit);

        button.on('click', function (e) {
          if (!content.is(':visible')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery(this).removeClass('action-primary');
            jQuery(this).addClass('action-secondary');
            jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            module_thing.slideToggle(300, function () {
              content.animate({'opacity': 1});
              button.attr('value', strButtonActive);
              button.css('margin-top', '0');
              button.fadeIn();
              cancel.css('display', 'block');
            });
          }
        });

        cancel.on("click", function (ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          jQuery(this).hide();
          button.removeClass('action-secondary');
          button.addClass('action-primary');
          content.css('opacity', 0);
          module_thing.slideToggle(300, function () {
            button.css('margin-top', '0.7em');
            button.attr('value', strButtonInit);
            button.removeAttr('disabled');
            jQuery('.required').val(''); // Need non-required elements cleared too, perhaps?
            var $newNoteTagInput = $('#tag_list');
            if ($newNoteTagInput.length) {
              $newNoteTagInput.tokenInput('clear');
              $newNoteTagInput.blur(); // Hides dropdown.
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

On page load, it's triggered like this:

```
var app = {
    initApp : function() {
        jQuery('form#new-placement-form.expandable-module').module_content_form_expander({'initial_button_text': 'Add a new placement', 'active_button_text': 'Add' });
    }
}

jQuery(function() {
    app.initApp();
}
```

It works fine, and it also works after refreshing the page in Chrome. However, on Firefox, it works only when the page is loaded for the firs time. After a refresh, it does nothing. Going to a different page, then coming back via a link makes it work again.

Firebug shows that the click handler for the event attached to `button` is not getting called when the button is clicked, although there are no errors and it looks like it attaches OK.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you write all of that code yourself or get it from somewhere else? Are you sure the on.click handlers should be inside the jQuery.fn.extend function?

Also, is everything wrapped inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
-----
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it, but I'm not too sure if I've missed something important. I've updated to show how it's called on page load. Where else could I put the click handlers (this is reused for multiple forms)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the expansion of the form thing, with it's disabling of the 'expand' button was causing Firefox to remember the disabled state on page refresh.

More info here: [Jquery UI button gets disabled on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719044/jquery-ui-button-gets-disabled-on-refresh)

I fixed it by removing the disabled state on the button every time the page loads.